# Use REGEXP_SUBSTR like a Split function

Tags: regex, oracle10g

I need to extract a text value from data in a VARCHAR2 column.  Sample:

`EDKES^Visit: ^PRIMARY INSURANCE COMMENTS: ^SECONDARY INSURANCE COMMENTS: ^TERTIARY INSURANCE COMMENTS: ^NO PRIMARY INSURANCE^NONE^NONE^NONE^NONE^NONE^NONE^NONE^NONE^NONE^NO SECONDARY INSURANCE^NONE^NONE^NONE^NONE^NONE^NONE^NONE^NONE^NONE^NO TERTIARY INS*`

I need to get the text that proceeds the 6th occurrence of the '^' (excluding the '^').  In this example, the text would be `NO PRIMARY INSURANCE`.

`([\w\s\:\*]+(\^?))` mostly works, but doesn't exclude the '^'.

When I try to use this expression `REGEXP_SUBSTR(VARCHAR_COL, '([\w\s\:\*]+(\^?))', 1, 6)`, I get a single character ('s'), rather than the expected match `NO PRIMARY INSURANCE^`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work pretty well:

```
REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(VARCHAR_COL, '[^^]+\^?', 1, 6), '^', '')
```

Comment: Does '^^' mean all characters but '^'?

Comment: @craig Exactly, but only when used as a character class: `[^^]`. Used on its own `^^` it matches the start of the string (twice).

Comment: the expression doesn't work as expected if a position doesn't have a value.  For example, applying the REGEX you suggested to `ONE^TWO^THREE^^FIVE^SIX^SEVEN` would return `SEVEN`, when I need it to return `SIX`.  Can you recommend a solution?

Comment: Interestingly, `[^^]+\^??` will eliminate the `^` from the results, so the `REPLACE` function isn't necessary.

Comment: @craig Try `'[^^]*\^?'`. The `+` requires at least one character, the `*` makes it optional. I have no way to test it, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to account for blank columns as well. And if the engine only returns
the capture groups, it will trim the delimiter.

`([^^]*).?`

This of course means that the last column found is always invalid.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like its limited to POSIX style. No lookarounds. If you are sure there will be no blank fields (ie `^^^this^that^^`) you should be able to use `[^^]+` and this trims the delimeter but it won't accept blank fields.